# Converting CELP audio files?

Tags: convert, audio

I've been tasked with converting CELP audio files (usually stored as .wav files) into a more mainstream format.  [CELP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-excited_linear_prediction) is a audio format specialized for speech and used in many voice recorders.

Does anyone know of any program capable of converting from the CELP format?

Comment: If they're stored as .wav files doesn't that mean they're in .wav format? How could they be a CELP file if they're a .wav file?

Comment: .wav is a container file format, you can have numerous different audio formats within.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:  [Switch](http://www.nch.com.au/switch/index.html) can convert CELP files if a CELP codec is installed.

Comment: Where did you get the CELP codec?

Comment: Can't remember but possibly came on a disc with the device.